# Null pointer exception double

Tags: java, double, nullpointerexception

Can somebody explain me why I am getting a `NullPointerException` here:

```
String s = request.getParameter("tbExample");
    _tbExample = new Double (Double.valueOf(s).doubleValue());
```

Comment: Also, there's rarely a good reason for new Double(Double.valueOf(s).doubleValue());   just use Double.valueOf(s)

Comment: What type is `request`? What are valid return values for `getParameter()`?

Comment: httpservletrequest and any number return will be fine.. if i set s as 0... if it is null it works but i have button on page that has retrieve back old data from database if user doesnt like what he changed so cant set it to 0 either

Comment: When you get NPE, you have a stack trace right? In the stack trace you can figure out which line threw the exception. If it's first line, then request is null; if it's the second line, then it's because s is null.

Answer (score 9):

s may be null. According to javadoc, if s is null, valueOf will throw a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking `s` for null before continuing.

Probably the `tbExample` parameter does not exist in your request.
Therefore null is being returned to indicate that fact, and is being assigned to `s`. This is then passed to `Double.valueOf`, which is invalid input.

Try something like this:

```
String s = request.getParameter("tbExample");
if(s == null)
{
    // Handle the error.
    // You could log something, throw exception, exit early, etc.
    // Do whatever is appropriate for your application.
}
else
{
    _tbExample = new Double (Double.valueOf(s).doubleValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see why you are confused here.  You are taking a `String`, parsing it into a `Double`, turning it into a `double` and back into a `Double` again.  A much simpler solution is to do

```
_tbExample = s == null ? null : Double.valueOf(s);
```

This handles the situation where `s` is `null` and turns a `String` into a `Double`

---

Here is a simple test program for you.

```
Double _tbExample;

String s = null;
_tbExample = s == null ? null : Double.valueOf(s);
System.out.println("_tbExample="+_tbExample);
```

prints

```
_tbExample=null
```

Comment: _tbExample =  Double.valueOf(s) is still giving me null pointer exception..plz help

Comment: @jack, I would have expected that. What happens when you try what I suggested?

Comment: it gives me the same nullpointer exception and points to same place after changes too

Comment: @jack, let me guess `_tbExample` is a `double`?  My mind reading powers a bit rusty. ;)

Comment: @jack `Double` and `double` are not the same thing.  Using `Double` will NOT cause a NullPointerException here.  Only use `double` would due to auto-unboxing.

Comment: @Jack, which is the point of adding `s == null ? null :` so `Double.valueOf()` is never called with a `null` have.